# How to compile a Rust kernel with an Assembly (NASM) bootloader

Tags: rust, operating-system, kernel, bootloader, rust-cargo

I have a simple 2-stage bootloader written in NASM, and I want to continue the OS kernel using Rust.

So I created a nightly Rust project with Cargo, and disabled std in the src/main.rs file. Now I am trying to link the Assembly files with the Cargo project, but without any success.

How should I compile and link the NASM bootloader with the Rust kernel?

Comment: Don't link them together. Have the linking of rust objects output to a binary file (I don't use rust, but you can use `objcopy` to convert an elf executable (generated by rust) to binary. Place the binary file on the disk where your bootloader will be reading the sectors from.You can do that with `dd`.

Comment: It appears there is a `bootimage` Rust project to create a bootable disk image that includes the Rust ELF executable.

Comment: Oops the link to the bootimage project is here: https://github.com/rust-osdev/bootimage

Comment: as far as I can tell the bootimage Rust project is just for compiling a kernel with a pre existing bootloader.  I have my own bootloader, so I don't think that it's the solution.

Comment: Then you will have to use something as I suggested in my first post. Likely your project is generating an ELF executable. Use `objcopy` to convert the ELF executable to binary. Convert it with something like `objcopy -O binary myos.elf myos.bin` then you can use `dd` to place the your bootloader in the first sector and `myos.bin` (or whatever name you wish) in the sectors after.You could just use `cat boot.bin myos.bin >disk.img` (or something similar if the OS is expected to be loaded from disk from right after the bootloader and assuming the boot.bin is exactly 512 bytes)

Comment: If you had another stage in there you'd have to add it in there as well. I generally use  DD to build disk images. It is easy to place things in the image where you need them. The primary thing is converting the rust ELF executable you generate to binary form (unless you coded an ELF loader into one of the earlier stages. Likely you didn't so it is easier to use binary images when loading.

Comment: The trick in Rust will be to ensure the entry point to your kernel is at the beginning of the binary (then you just have your second stage jump t the first address where the kernel was loaded in memory). I don't know how to do that in the Rust environment but it usually entails creating a linker script to place the start code before all other code and data in the kernel.

Comment: I already looked up how to "bootimage" project compiles bootloaders with Rust and it was similar to what you suggested. I looked up how to compile Rust to an ELF executable, but I didn't find an answer. Could you write the command to compile Rust into an ELF executable?

Comment: Have you already generated a kernel executable from your current project?

Comment: I have created a .o file and a normal Linux executable. I did not find the right flags to compile the kernel so I can boot to it.

Comment: You may find someone who uses Rust over on OSDev.org that may know https://forum.osdev.org/ . Or you can wait around here until someone with Rust experience sees this on SO. Probably doesn't hurt to ask in both places. OSDev is generally _C/C++_ OS developers but I have seen some discuss Rust at times as well. You could also ask on https://www.reddit.com/r/osdev/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a couple of hours I compiled the code.

The solution was (like Michael Petch suggested), to compile the assembly code into static `.o` files, then compile the rust code using `xargo` and a custom target. I compiled the Rust code as a static library, not a binary, so the output was a `.a` object file, and not an executable.

Then I used `gcc` with a linker script to link together the object files and output the result as an ELF file. After that I used `objcopy` to with the `-O binary` flag to copy the ELF file to a .bin file. And finally I used `dd` to create an image file, that I could boot from.

Answer (score 0):

How I went about linking the NASM bootloader to a Rust kernel were as follows:

I first initialized a Rust project with `cargo` and created a custom i386 Rust target similar looking to this

```json
{
    "llvm-target": "i386-unknown-none",
    "data-layout": "e-m:e-i32:32-f80:128-n8:16:32-S128-p:32:32",
    "arch": "x86",
    "target-endian": "little",
    "target-pointer-width": "32",
    "target-c-int-width": "32",
    "os": "none",
    "executables": true,
    "linker-flavor": "ld.lld",
    "linker": "rust-lld",
    "panic-strategy": "abort",
    "disable-redzone": true,
    "features": "-mmx,-sse,+soft-float"
}
```

I then wrote some Rust code in the `main.rs` file following the directions in [this guide](https://os.phil-opp.com/minimal-rust-kernel/#printing-to-screen) linked specifying `#[no_mangle]`, `#![no_std]`, `#![no_main]` and `#[panic_handler]` where necessary.

In my `cargo.toml`, I specified to Rust to create a static library `*.a` file, since you cannot link a binary with a binary

```ini
[lib]
name = "sapphire"           # The name of the target.
path = "src/main.rs"    # The source file of the target.
edition = "2021"       # The edition of the target.
crate-type = ["staticlib"]   # The crate types to generate.
```

I then created a `.cargo/config.toml` to build the `compiler_builtins`, `compiler-builtins-mem` and `core`

After writing the Rust file, I then wrote a simple bootloader in assembly, switching from real mode to protected mode following along with the [Boot Sequence](https://wiki.osdev.org/Boot_Sequence) specification on OSDev.

I wrote a linker script to link together the Rust kernel and the bootloader,

```
SECTIONS {
    . = 0x7C00;
    .text : {
        /* *(.text) */
        chainloader.elf(.text)
    }
    .text : {
        kernel.a(.text)
    }
    
    /DISCARD/ : {
        *(.comment)
        *(.eh_frame)
        *(.rel.eh_frame)
        *(.note.gnu.property)
    }
}
```

placing the bootloader first and adding the offset required to be detected by the [Bootstrap Loader Service](http://vitaly_filatov.tripod.com/ng/asm/asm_001.12.html)

I then built the bootloader as an ELF file, linked it to the kernel with the emulation `elf_i386` and converted the ELF file to a binary using `objcopy`.

Finally, I flashed the image using `dd` and booted it with an emulator.